# VS 2015 Python Environments Greyed Out

Tags: ptvs

I'm just getting started with Python and I want to use Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (VS) for writing my code.  However, after diligently following the instructions on GitHub (1) Install PTVS 2.2.2 (2) Install Windows Python 3.4.4, VS cannot find the Python interpreter and run the code.  When I attempt to do so for VS manually via Options > Python Tools > Environment Option, all the buttons are greyed out (I cannot enter information) as well as the Python Environment Window

[image: See Screenshot]

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, repairing and modifying VS, PTVS and Python 3.4 but to no avail.  Is there something I'm missing?  Much appreciate the help!

Comment: I have this same problem after accidentally selecting python 3.6 which isn't supported.  Nothing fixes the issues (including reinstalls) right now.

Comment: I have the same issue with python 3.6 when auto-detect is used it crashes VS and then "+ custom" is grayed out. TO which I then had use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430831/vs-2015-python-environments-greyed-out) to get it to become available again

Comment: I thought I would mention I logged this bug on their site as issue [29201](http://bugs.python.org/index?@action=oic_authresp&state=wB6OBYipipu5fh28&code=4/AXUeRwU-ZRvtpweqA73554NysgPzp6EJ7glkRIBoHrU&authuser=0&session_state=649df5a89bf2b1d93b4afef249fce561e6d5e7b8..ae54&prompt=consent#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right-tap the lower-left corner and choose Run in the Quick Access
   Menu.
2. Type regedit and tap OK in the Run dialog. Go to:
   KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\PythonTools\Interpreters
3. Delete or Rename folder in this directory (you can see that some keys are referring to the 3.6 version).
4. Start Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Why is it after I do this and everything is working I try to go back to 'Python Environment' and click the auto-detect VS restarts itself and the project losses access to the previously setup Environment pointing at the interpreter? Plus going back into Python Environments there are none showing and the "+ Custom+ is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

It seems Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition does not like Python 3.6.
If you just edit the registry:

```
KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\PythonTools\Interpreters
```

as Luciano suggested, and replace the version key from 3.6 to 3.5 it works.