# MS Visual Studio-Python Environment-Adding an interpreter- "+ Custom..." greyed out

Tags: python, visual-studio, interpreter

First time posting! Really stuck, need experienced help. I am a mechanical engineering student with a small amount of c programming experience, about to tackle a personal project using Python, which I will learn to use as-I-go.

Trying to add an interpreter to the Python Environment in MS Visual Studio 2015 (VS).

Downloaded Python 3.6, at the time I did not realize 3.5 was recommended by MS for use with VS. VS did not find Python 3.6 automatically, so I tried to add the path manually using "+ Custom...". 3.6 wasn't an option in the edition dropdown, so tried to type it in. When I "Applied", the program stopped working. After restarting VS, Python is still not added, and the "+ Custom" button is greyed out, not allowing me to add the proper Python 3.5 or any other interpreter not automatically recognized.

The only interpreter I have successfully added since is IronPython, which is automatically recognized. Python 3.6, 3.5, 3.4.4 were installed but not automatically recognized.

Web searches only provided this: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1760
The person had the same problem but only recovered use of the "+ custom" button by reinstalling his operating system and VS. I would like to avoid this extreme repair strategy.

I have restarted my computer and VS many times throughout troubleshooting. I am confident that once the "+ Custom..." button becomes active, the rest of the interpreter install will go fine.

Alternatively, If there is a lower-level way to add interpreters to the Python Environment, I would attempt that strategy if some guidance were provided.

Thank you for considering

Comment: I was able to find where my python path was, but when I add manually it gives the error that interpreter is not found. If I auto-detect after placing the path in it crashes VS and the "+ custom" then grays out. So I am currently in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove PTVS 2.2.5 and install an older version like PTVS 2.2 and you should be able to use the "+ custom" button again...

Comment: How do you do what you recommend. Also the custom button is active again after doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430831/vs-2015-python-environments-greyed-out)

Comment: I have the same issue as him having installed pyhton 3.6 and it crashes VS when I try to auto=detect